# No route matches POST when updating rails-api gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, railscasts, rails-api

When I add this to my gem file ( rails 4.0.1 )

```
gem 'rails-api', git: 'https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api.git', branch: 'master'
```

My routes seem to break (although rake routes is the same before/after)

I get this after I attempt to update a simple scaffold model

**No route matches [POST] "/surveys/1"** when I update a record

by commenting out this gem it works again - any ideas what I did wrong?

thanks!

PS: Adding this to gem file so I can use strong parameters to follow railscasts#196 in rails 4

Comment: In Rails 4 the preferred HTTP verb for updates is PATCH.

Answer (score 0):

> Adding this to gem file so I can use strong parameters to follow
>   railscasts#196 in rails 4

Perhaps your app is having a problem with what you're using this gem for. I don't know if you've just upgraded to Rails 4, but the latest version uses [Strong Params by default](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

The Railscast seems to be involved with loading nested forms. We do this all the time without the `rails-api` gem - can you let us know what you're trying to use this gem for specifically?